# Numerical model for a Air core Vortex, why it's still so limited?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, turbulence, navier-stokes, vortex

The Question can be [Formally presented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_question#Types_and_purpose) as follows;

**How** is the Numerical Model (CFD, Navier Stokes) **of** fluid dynamics **for** Vortexes **at** in it's limits?

[At this Publication](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~vawweb/vaw_mitteilungen/220/220.pdf) from 2013 at page 48 is said;

> If the free surface is bent at the at the dimple, the complexity and the velocity gradient in the air core is growing fast. At this stage the actual limit is reached that numerical simulations can provide nowadays.

and continued at page 49;

> An even more sophisticated step would be an adequate simulation of the air entrainment itself, which is still not possible.

**QUESTION; Why it's still not possible?**

There is many "[exact solutions of NS-equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations#Exact_solutions_of_the_Navier.E2.80.93Stokes_equations)" for Vortexes; 
Ie. [Burgers Vortex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers_vortex) and [Lamb-Oseen vortex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamb%E2%80%93Oseen_vortex)

Basically Vortex has a clear construction, which can mainly be expressed mathematically very simply way. Ie [Rankine Vortex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankine_vortex) An example of this construction is picture below; 
[image: Vortex pattern]

If you look the German-wiki from the ["Lamb-Oseen vortex"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamel-Oseenscher-Wirbel#Umfangsgeschwindigkeit) you find this picture, I modified it to show the interes of my Question (green line).

[image: Vortex velocity]

I am interested about there true shape of this peak. How the numerical model's works at this peak compared to experiments. I think here lies the problem. It's clear that most of the Vortexes aren't like "Lamb-Oseen", but I doubt if they are abslutely like the "Rankine" either. So it's something like the "Burger". When i think the current calculation power, it sound not reasonable that the problem lies just on complexity, as there is even exact solutions available.

Few aspects;

- Energy dissipation rate predicted by the "Lamb-Oseen" is too big, compared to reality.
- [Rankine Vortex has an extra pressure gradient in the Water, directed inwards, that prevents evolution of the rigid-body flow to the irrotational state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortex#Rotational_vortices). The counter force of this, might be an extra pressure gradient directed outwards the rigid-body, and this might be the cause to such an stable air core, as told here; [How deep can a whirlpool descend?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/202899/how-deep-can-a-whirlpool-descend/212379#212379)
- There is [really interesting experiments made](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWvJLs47EKg) which are able to visualize this phenomenon very nice.
- I am thinking the area marked with red line &question mark in the first picture?

Comment: Why must it have an exact solution if it is commonly seen?

Comment: @KyleKanos "easily reproducible" is not "commonly seen", most "exact solution" in the provided list are also easy to verify in the lab. I do found stuff like this; http://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/cfx/21544-free-surface-vortex-flow.html and paper's like ie. Tomoyoshi Okamura 2007 stating; "The calculated streamlines and Vortex core lines are not able to be used to predict the visible vortices with much accuracy." or this kind of videos; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lwtGJeebwg8 which seems to be very unrealistic; like the old films with wrong Reynolds number.

Comment: I'm not sure why "easily reproducible" is not equivalent to "commonly seen" (anyone who has tried draining a full sink will have seen it), but that's not really important. What *is* important is whether or not there are reproducible fluid dynamic experiments that *don't* have analytic solutions. If these exist, then your present thesis is unfounded.

Comment: @KyleKanos Well, yes, if you start this with complete still stand, you don't have any analytic solution; it can rotate either way, or not at all. But if you give some initial rotation, you will always get an Vortex with air core. And I expect this vortex should have analytic solution. -But I see a flaw in my question; the start direction must be given, or othervice we are just throwing a dice. The point is that I am simply seeking a realistic CFD of an air core vortex.

Comment: Well the NS equations *do* lead to the [vorticity equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorticity_equation), so I'm not sure why you'd suspect that something that's been verified time and time again is somehow mistaken because you can't find someone who's created one particular simulation...

Comment: Though it [seems like this YouTube video does what you want....](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHxyFKOQVxY)

Comment: @KyleKanos Thank's for the link, though there is no vortex. Vorticity is not the same as Vortex, which is not same as air core vortex. My problem is that I can't find any numerical model for air core vortex which has produced realistic results. I also felt this a bit amazing myself, as the center of aircore vortex is mostly a rigid-body-like-vortex. If this is so trivially verified I just need a link and I will delete this question with apologies.

Comment: I think this question has gone from *unclear* (v1) to *too narrow* (v3,v4). The current question is basically asking for a Yes or No answer, which isn't a good fit for the site. We prefer questions that would actually give an explanation (e.g., asking how one might model this situation might be better, but could be borderline homework or off-topic for computational reasons).

Comment: I added the Formal question, and noticed myself that it might now be reconsidered as a dublicate; ie. http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15738/have-we-figured-out-how-to-analyze-turbulent-fluids/  Though I have slightly different approach.